# How to make LEFT JOIN with row having max date?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, left-join, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables in Oracle DB

```
Person (
  id
)

Bill (
  id,
  date,
  amount,
  person_id
)
```

I need to get person and amount from last bill if exist.
I trying to do it this way

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  b.amount
FROM Person p
LEFT JOIN Bill b
ON b.person_id = p.id AND b.date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM Bill WHERE person_id = 1)
WHERE p.id = 1;
```

But this query works only with INNER JOIN. In case of LEFT JOIN it throws `ORA-01799 a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery`

How can I get amoun from the last bill using left join?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: By the `ORA-0199` I guess Oracle

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by amount from last bill ?? Also provide some data for the tables if possible.

Comment: @Nikhil amount from Bill with max date or null

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please try the below avoiding sub query to be outer joined

```
SELECT
 p.id,
 b.amount
 FROM Person p
 LEFT JOIN(select * from Bill where date =
 (SELECT MAX(date) FROM Bill b1 WHERE person_id = 1)) b ON b.person_id = p.id 
 WHERE p.id = 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is a way to tell in `bills`, for each person, what is the latest record, and that one is the one to join with. One way is to use `row_number`:

```
select * from person p
left join (select b.*, 
                  row_number() over (partition by person_id order by date desc) as seq_num 
           from bills b) b
on p.id = b.person_id
and seq_num = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have a subquery inside an `ON` statement.
Instead you need to convert your `LEFT JOIN` statement into a whole subquery.

Not tested but this should work.

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  b.amount
FROM Person p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id FROM Bill
    WHERE person_id = p.id
        AND date = (SELECT date FROM Bill WHERE person_id = 1)) b
WHERE p.id = 1;
```

I'm not quite sure why you would want to filter for the date though.
Simply filtering for the `person_id` should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can do like this

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  b.amount
FROM Person p
LEFT JOIN Bill b
ON b.person_id = p.id AND b.date = (SELECT max(date) FROM Bill WHERE person_id = 1)
WHERE p.id = 1
```

Comment: I misspelled. This is the exactly my query

Comment: I have added max keyword!

Answer (score 1):

you should join Person and Bill to the result for max date in bill related to person_id

```
  select Person.id, bill.amount
  from Person
  left join bill on  bill.person_id = person.id
  left join (
  select person_id, max(date) as max_date
  from bill 
  group by person_id ) t on t.person_id = Person.id and b.date = t.max_date
```

Comment: Change the second "left join" to just "join":
join (
  select person_id, max(date) as max_date
  from bill 
  group by person_id )

and then it will work as it should do

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  b.amount
FROM Person p
LEFT JOIN Bill b
ON b.person_id = p.id 
WHERE (SELECT max(date) FROM bill AS sb WHERE sb.person_id=p.id LIMIT 1)=b.date;
```

Comment: Please explain how this answer is different from the 4 previous answers

Comment: its fetch data for all person in one query which is not in ashwin sathawane answer and all other query r more complex in my view

Comment: if we need to fetch for particular  person id and amount no need to join with person table because both are available in bill table so our query is

SELECT person_id,amount FROM Bill where person_id=1 order by date DESC LIMIT 1;

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT
      p.id,
      c.amount
    FROM Person p
    LEFT JOIN (select b.person_id as personid,b.amount as amount from Bill b where b.date1= (select max(date1) from Bill where person_id=1)) c
    ON c.personid = p.id
    WHERE p.id = 1;
```

Comment: Please explain how this answer is different from the 5 previous answers

Answer (score 1):

### try this

```
select * from person p
left join (select  MAX(id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY date DESC) 
           from bills b) b
on p.id = b.person_id
```

Comment: Please explain in what this answer solves better or at all the problem compared to the previous 6 answers

Comment: you can match all of those answers, which is faster? what are the costs?(you can look explain plan) then select one of them @GiladGreen

Answer (score 0):

I use GREATEST() function in join condition:

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    b.amount
FROM Person p
LEFT JOIN Bill b
    ON b.person_id = p.id
    AND b.date = GREATEST(b.date)
WHERE p.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This allows you to grab the whole row if necessary and grab the top x rows

```
SELECT p.id
  ,b.amount
FROM person p
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT * FROM 
        (
            SELECT date
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY date DESC) AS row_num 
            FROM bill
        )
        WHERE row_num = 1
    ) b ON p.id = b.person_id
WHERE p.id = 1
;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).